# How different numbers are added at the beginning of each line?

Tags: bash

I have got this file :

```
...
chapter 10.
1. text
2. text
text
3. text
chapter 11.
1. text
2. text
3. text
4. text
chapter 12.
1. text
text
text
2. text
...
```

And I need this

```
...
chapter 10.
10.1. text
10.2. text
text
10.3. text
chapter 11.
11.1. text
11.2. text
11.3. text
11.4. text
chapter 12.
12.1. text
text
text
12.2. text
...
```

I have to put the number that comes after the chapter at the beginning of all the following lines that begin with a number followed by a dot. There are lines that do not begin with a number, those would remain unchanged. Thank you very much, any help is welcome

Comment: Did you try `awk` for that?

Comment: Now that we know what you need, and what the expected output is ... What have you **tried** to solve this problem?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -i~ -pe '$ch = $1  if /^chapter ([0-9]+\.)/;
              print $ch if /^[0-9]+\./;
     ' -- file.txt
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, printing each line after processing;
- `-i~` saves all the changes to the original file, a backup file is created with the extension `~`;
- when a line starts with `chapter XX.`, the number of the chapter including the final dot is saved in the variable `$ch`;
- when the line starts with a number followed by a dot, the value from `$ch` is prepended.